# Openflow 1.3 and ip multicast support

Tags: replication, multicast, openflow

I'm just starting w/ OpenFlow 1.3, and i'd like to know if it support ip multicast e.g. replication?
If yes, where could i get the documentation, CLI's.

Comment: have you checked offical documentation available? https://www.opennetworking.org

Answer (score 3):

OpenFlow 1.3 supports Group Table. Then you can do multicast by having a group table with multiple buckets, and each bucket outputs to a designed port.

Update: Ryu igmp controller written in Python:
https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/simple_switch_igmp.py